# CIDepthBlurEffect rendering issue on iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, core-image, depth, cifilter

I have following that works fine on iOS 11:

```
let ciContext       = CIContext(options: [kCIContextWorkingFormat : kCIFormatRGBAh])  
var outputImage     : CIImage  
let mainImage       = CIImage(data: jpegData)  
let disparityImage  = CIImage(data: jpegData, options: [kCIImageAuxiliaryDisparity : true])  
let filter          = CIFilter(name: "CIDepthBlurEffect",  
                      withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey : mainImage!,  
                      kCIInputDisparityImageKey: disparityImage!])  
outputImage         = filter!.outputImage!
```

---

### Issue

Rendtition was fine until iOS 12, where everything is blurred out.  This was with every beta so far.  The whole image is in blur.

I couldn't find any API change notes on this, also `CIDepthBlurEffect` is not documented to begin with.

Comment: Did you file a radar that I can duplicate?

Comment: Radar 42623770.

Comment: Can you push the content to http://www.openradar.me? FYI I can recommend using https://github.com/br1sk/brisk to publish to both Apples Bug Report and Open Radar.